# Driving a loudspeaker

Tags: speakers

I've been thinking about this on and off for a while and I thought I would ask the experts.

The cone and coil of a loudspeaker have mass, so it takes time and energy to move the cone to another position. This led me to think that surely the actual position of the loudspeaker over time does not precisely reflect the amplitude driving it, and that this would presumably be more apparent for higher amplitudes and frequencies.

So i was thinking: **why aren't loudspeakers designed to be driven by the derivative of the signal, or some normalised mixture of both?** That way, drastic changes in amplitude per sample will result in more power to move the cone to where it needs to be.

Comment: What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: It seems to work well enough for audiophools, so why not? But well, maybe now they have another thing they need in their HyFly equipment...

Comment: I think I can half-get what you mean, but because they are driven by AC really the absolute position doesn't matter it's the relative difference. Don't do this at least with an expensive speaker but if you connect a DC battery to a speaker it will extend the cone, but after maybe an initial pop you won't have any sound output.

Answer (score 2):

There's a key misconception in your question.

The electrical signal that represents a sound wave is proportional to the instantaneous pressure of the sound wave.

When a speaker is used to reproduce the sound, the pressure of the wave is NOT proportional to the position of the cone, but rather it is proportional to the cone's velocity. In other words, the coupling between speaker position and acoustic pressure acts as a high-pass filter (differentiator), and the low-pass characteristic (integration) of the speaker drive mechanism that you describe is exactly what you want in order to compensate for that.

It isn't perfect, but it works well enough. The rest can be taken care of by electronic equalization.

Answer (score 0):

There are processors on the Pro-Audio market that monitor driver performance and use high speed signal sampling and DSP processing to correct the signal accordingly for best driver response.

A speaker's cone and voice coil doesn't have that much mass (it's only paper and wire). 
Not a huge mass for a Electro-magnetic force to move, which is considered one of the most powerful forces in the universe....